# C#, how to get only GET parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, get

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params` seems to return way too many params, including headers, etc... How can I efficiently only retrieve GET or POST parameters ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

use Request.QueryString Collection for GET paras and Request.Form Collection for POST ones.

e.g.

```
var someValueFromGet = Request.QueryString["YourGetPara"];
var someValueFromPost = Request.Form["YourPostPara"];
```

please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: please elaborate with a bit of code [read this meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers)

Comment: In MVC 6 `Request.QueryString["YourGetPara"]` becomes `Request.Query["YourGetPara"]`